# Как убрать элемент шаблона?

Tags: joomla

В общем, есть шаблон, а там есть 2 ненужных элемента (social bookmarks, поиск по сайту).
Как их убрать?

Answer (score 1):

В **административной панели**, в разделе **"модули"** - найди нужный модуль (элемент как ты говоришь) и **отмени публикацию** (или совсем удали)